# Convert PHP object to array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I've seen other solutions on StackOverflow, but my scenario is a bit different.

I have a charts factory in PHP that receives an array of strings, for example:

```
$charts = ['SomeChart', 'SomeOtherChart', 'AndAnotherChart'];
```

and then it loops through an array, returns a new class if it exists and then runs a default method called 'run'.

```
foreach($charts as $key => $param) {
    try {
        if($chart = ChartsFactory::build($param)) {
            $result['charts'][$param] = $chart->run();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $result[$param] = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and then I `return $result;`.

Inside my view, I want to pass that `result` to `JavaScript`. So I do this:

`var result = <?php echo json_encode($result);?>;`

It all works fine, but the only problem is that `JavaScript` receives an `Object` instead of an `Array`, which is not what I want because I want want to run forEach on it and some other `Array` related stuff.

How can I convert it to `Array` or make sure that it receives an `Array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, arrays can only contain numeric indexes, that's why PHP outputs an associative array with string indexes as a JavaScript object, which is the closest representation.

You can, however, iterate over a JavaScript object's properties:

```js
for (var name in myObject) {
   // value = myObject[name]
}
```